# Unity resolving generic event handlers

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container, dependency-resolver

I'm using Unity to register all my domain event handlers like such :

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<IDomainEventHandler<ProductCreated>, ProductCreatedHandler>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
}
```

My handler looks like this :

```
public class ProductCreatedHandler : IDomainEventHandler<ProductCreated>
{
    public void Handle(ProductCreated domainEvent)
    {
        // Handle the event
    }
}
```

My domain event looks like this :

```
public class ProductCreated : IDomainEvent
{
    private Product product;

    public ProductCreated(Product product)
    {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

And I raise this event using :

```
var product = new Product()
{
    ProductGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    ProductCode = productCode,
    ProductName = productName,
};

DomainEvents.Raise<ProductCreated>(new ProductCreated(product));
```

And I handle raised events with the following code :

```
public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
{
    if (Container != null)
    {
        foreach (var handler in Container.ResolveAll<IDomainEventHandler<T>>())
        {
            handler.Handle(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the inspector, `T` is a `ProductCreated` type but `Container.ResolveAll<IDomainEventHandler<T>>()` does not resolve anything, even though through the inspector I can see that the `Container` does have a registration to this registered type `IDomainEventHandler` with the mapped type being `ProductCreatedHandler`

Why is the container not resolving the generic type that I register at the start ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResolveAll` only resolves named registrations, try registering your handler with a name, like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IDomainEventHandler<ProductCreated>, ProductCreatedHandler>("ProductCreatedHandler", new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

This can be seen under Remarks in the documentation for [`ResolveAll<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff661778(v=pandp.30).aspx):

> Be aware that this method does NOT return an instance for the default (unnamed) registration.